# why is dhcpd listening on UDP port 38053 and udp6 port 40572?

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcpd

I am running a DHCP server with `dhcpd` from ISC and thought it should only be listening on port 67.  Why is it also listening on those other ports?  I cannot seem to find what those ports are for, but my guess is they provide remote administration of some sort even though I don't have it explicitly called out in my configuration file.

Comment: this is normal, those are just connecting to your router or maybe your DNS cache(or both)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, I think this behavior is linked to the `NSUPDATE` dhcp / dns update functionality ("dynamic DNS"). `dh_client` also opens extra UDP ports on my machine.

See [this Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1176046) and the linked [Debian user forum discussion](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=95273) for some additional details, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an option to prevent `dh_client` / `dhcpd` from listening on these ports.